# How we can consume Odataservice without generating proxy

Tags: web-services, wcf, odata

I am planning to `OData` service to built entrprise data bus which will be getting consumed by Business service. Business service then will be having services to various clients like web site, smart phones,etc

To start with I am looking to consume Odata service in Business service without generating proxy(without adding as service reference).

I found one article which explain how to consume `WCF` service without using service reference [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/accessing-wcf-service-without-creating-proxy/). This looks great in scenario where we will be having separate project for service contract and data contract. Can we have similar for Odata services also?

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but unlike WCF Soap services, OData does not 'require' a proxy to consume. It is an http protocol and the response will come back as plain xml or json without the message contract infrastructure of WCF. There is the Atom Pub syndication format which you will have to deal with, but .Net has libraries for that.

Generating a proxy from a service reference for OData services is probably just a convenience for clients to work with a strongly typed model, but not a requirement.

To verify this, simply hit your OData service with a simple url request and view the response in your browser (turn off automatic RSS readers) or in Fiddler. If your business layer can deserialize the response, you are ready to go without a proxy.

If you are accessing it from a javascript client, there are some js libraries that can help with the deserialization as well, such as [JayData](http://jaydata.org/) and [datajs](http://datajs.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

1. odatajs (Olingo Oclient for Javascript ) : http://olingo.apache.org/doc/javascript/download.html
2. odata library (.net ) : http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Client/
3. Olingo OData client for java: http://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/

more @ http://www.odata.org/libraries/